# Sitecore security - combining roles

Tags: security, sitecore

Is there a way to combine access rights for a Sitecore item?

For example, I have a page that I would like to lock down to users who are a member of two different roles rather than just just one, and a user who has just one of the roles should be denied access.

I know you can have roles within roles but wondering if there was a simpler way to achieve this?

I'm using Sitecore 7.2.

Comment: The roles within roles feature sounds like exactly the feature you are after. What don't you like about it?

Comment: I presume you're using Webforms? How many pages are we talking and does permission inheritance matter (from parent to children) down the tree matter? i.e. are you also trying to remove access to an entire content branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to check this in code, you can easily do so using

```
var user = AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser();
return user.IsInRole("Role1") && user.IsInRole("Role2") ? "Granted":"Denied";
```

But if you are trying to achieve this in Sitecore Security on an item, then an AND of those 2 roles will be assigned. Ex: If I allow access to an item in Role1 but deny in Role2, the user with Roles 1 and 2 will have his/her access denied.

Comment: Thanks, so there's no way to achieve it without code? There's nothing that can be done in the security editor?

Comment: I am unaware of any solution that lets you do that. In my opinion you should keep Roles/Access simple and normalized. I prefer to not mix roles for simplicity. I would recommend that for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to approach this is to define a new role with appropriate access rights and assign the relevant users to it, either manually or by script. That keeps your access rights transparent. You could code your way around the issue, but you could end up creating an admin nightmare, where it's near to impossible to see which roles and users have access to which items. E.g. what would you expect to see in the Access Viewer when looking at one of the roles, or at a user with one or both of the roles? There's a big difference between assigning access rights programmatically and evaluating them programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

One way that you could achieve it via the `Security Editor` is by utilising Sitecore's `Roles in Roles` functionality.

Essentially you will want to create a New Role in the `Role Manager` that will contain the two roles, Role A and Role B. Select your New Role in the `Role Manager` and click  `Member Of` button. In the modal click Add and select the two roles this New Role needs to contain.

[image]

In the `Security Editor` select the New Role and assign the read, write, create etc permissions to the required `Items`.

Now when users access those `Items` they must have Role A and Role B before given access - **they will not need the New Role assigned to their account**.

If you have a large number of roles to manage and combinations of those it will be very time consuming to manually create those combinations.

Comment: Maybe someone can suggest a way to automate those role creations

Comment: I don't think this will work, there's no way to enforce that they must be member of BOTH groups, roles in roles will still only check they are a member of ANY group.

Comment: Ah, that's a bit of a pain. Always viewed Roles in Roles as a logical AND not a simple collection of Roles. Might be worth looking if anything custom can be done to achieve using Roles in Roles like that.

Comment: Ahh. Any modules out there or any other means to achieve it?